# Project Missing Default Error Templates Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i am trying to make default 500 error template for my Symfony project, i created

```
/app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/exception.html.twig
```

and also i cleared cache

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

But my browser still shows default error template from browser

(there was no default error templates in my folder)

Does anyone know how i can solve this issue? any good tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your `exception.html.twig` to `error.html.twig`.

Symfony 4 and above:

```
/templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error.html.twig
/templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error404.html.twig
```

Symfony 3 and below:

```
/app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.twig
/app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig
```

For more information, see:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html